# How to append into field

Tags: append, livecode

How can I append a text into a text field. I tried something like:

```
on mouseUp
    append "Once again" into "field display"
end mouseUp
```

Where "display" is a Scrolling field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Put "hello" after field "display"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append to a specific line, and since you have a scrolling field this may be what you really asked for:

put space & "Hello World" after line 3 of fld "yourScrollingField".

Know also that you could:

put space & "Hello World" after word 3 of line 3 of fld "yourScrollingField".

Check out all three chunk keywords, "before", "into" and "after" in the dictionary. Chunk expressions permit exquisite control of text down to the character level.

Answer (score 1):

Or...

```
  put cr & "This is a new line of text." after field "display"
```

Why?

"after" is quite literal, equal in effect to "&".